# Text blurry on hover with scale transformed element

Tags: css

I'm ripping my hair out with this bug, so any help is greatly appreciated. If you go to the fiddle you we see that when you hover over the button it scales, but as this happens the text blurs. I've tried various ways to fix this but feel like I'm falling to the rabbit hole! Thank you :)

I want the text to never be blurry on hover, or as it transitions.

Ps, I'm working in Chrome.

https://jsfiddle.net/u2mpaLa7/

```css
.btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">Button Text</div>
```

Comment: it blurs during the transition is done, which is logic for me .. so what is the problem ?

Comment: see if adding `backface-visibility:hidden;` to your `.btn` helps at all

Comment: The objective is to not have the text blur at all. backface leaves the text blurred.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is related to scale.

You can accomplish the same thing with this CSS but without the "blurring" effect you are getting:

https://jsfiddle.net/y9jv7o3r/

```
.btn:hover { 
margin-top: -5px; 
margin-left: -5px; 
padding: 15px 25px; 
font-size: 18px; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, but now there is an issue with the font wobbling?

Comment: I'd just avoid making the text bigger then - since that seems to be your biggest problem. https://jsfiddle.net/ubywx9pq/

Answer (score 1):

Often, different `transform` effects have these 'blurness' issues due to font rendering, I doubt there is a simple fix... However, te desired effect can easily be achieved without using `transform`, just keeping it simple: `font-size`, `padding` and `margin`; keep it simple.

Doing it whis way will also be good for accesability as Firefox and Opera will not support scale.

Comment: I agree with keeping it simple, stick to the basics.

What I don't understand though, is why do think Firefox and Opera won't support scale. 
They do, I'm browsing this thread with Opera and doublechecked with Firefox. Or are you talking about Opera Mini? https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: You're right, `scale` won't give any problems, I was thinking of `zoom`. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom